# FitNesse, InstantiationException: No responder for autoComplete

Tags: fitnesse, instantiationexception

Situation: I have FitNesse installed on a virtual machine. FitNesse is installed and test-suite is configured in the past. Now I can run the scripts. But when I want to edit and save a script I get an error message. The error shown (I removed the location-path and file-name):

WARNING: An error occured while fulfilling user request [No responder for autoComplete]
java.lang.InstantiationException: No responder for autoComplete
at fitnesse.responders.ResponderFactory.lookupResponder(ResponderFactory.java:151)
at fitnesse.responders.ResponderFactory.makeResponder(ResponderFactory.java:129)
at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.createGoodResponse(FitNesseExpediter.java:143)
at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.makeResponse(FitNesseExpediter.java:112)
at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.run(FitNesseExpediter.java:51)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
WARNING: An error occured while fulfilling user request [java.io.FileNotFoundException: .[location][name of file].wiki (Access is denied)]

I checked the location itself via file-explorer and I do have access to create new files or edit files on that location.
My colleague, who also has access to the same virtual machine, does not have this issue.
Someone who has any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific: what kind of virtual machine are you using, how was FitNesse installed, which version of FitNesse are your running? It seems quite strange that a colleague would not have the same error running the same VM, as one would expect the point of virtual machines is to offer identical environments. Is there anything different between two to setups (host/client machine, version, OS, ...)?

Comment: The difference is that I am the owner of the VM and my colleague has read/write access for that VM. So I now in contact with VM-support to check if it is related to that.

Comment: Are you both running FitNesse from the same folder on the VM? The error suggests you are missing the toolchain-plugin jar, or have no read access for it. (as the autoComplete responder is not part of FitNesse, but of that particular plugin).